# adding the same object twice to a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two django model classes:

```
class A(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)    #irrelevant

class B(models.Model):
     a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)    #irrelevant
```

What I want to do is the following:

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
b = B()

b.a.add(a1)
b.a.add(a1)    #I want to have a1 twice
b.a.add(a2)

assert len(b.a.all()) == 3 #this fails; the length of all() is 2
```

I am guessing that add() uses a set semantic, but how can I circumvent that? I tried looking into custom managers, but I am not sure if this the right way (seems complicated)...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is to use an intermediary model to form the M2M relationship using the `through` keyword argument in the ManyToManyField. Sort of like the first answer above, but more "Django-y".

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A, through='C')
    ...

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

When using the `through` keyword, the usual M2M manipulation methods are no longer available (this means `add`, `create`, `remove`, or assignment with `=` operator). Instead you must create the intermediary model itself, like so:

```
 >>> C.objects.create(a=a1, b=b)
```

However, you will still be able to use the usual querying operations on the model containing the `ManyToManyField`. In other words the following will still work:

```
 >>> b.a.filter(a=a1)
```

But maybe a better example is something like this:

```
>>> B.objects.filter(a__name='Test')
```

As long as the FK fields on the intermediary model are not designated as `unique` you will be able to create multiple instances with the same FKs. You can also attach additional information about the relationship by adding any other fields you like to `C`.

Intermediary models are documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

Answer (score 4):

Django uses a relational DB for its underlying storage, and that intrinsically DOES have "set semantics": no way to circumvent THAT. So if you want a "multi-set" of anything, you have to represent it with a numeric field that counts how many times each item "occurs". ManyToManyField doesn't do that -- so, instead, you'll need a separate Model subclass which explicitly indicates the A and the B it's relating, AND has an integer property to "count how many times".

Comment: I think that's not entirely correct. The relation from A to B is realized via a relation table comprised of three columns: id, a_id and b_id. id is the primary key of that table, so it would be OK to have three rows in that table where two have the same entry for a_id and b_id respectively. And this is what I want, but I can't figure out how to tell Django that...

Comment: @qolin, sos-skil's answer offers you a way to make such a table (not via manytomany of course) -- my idea is just to add a count field to that table rather than relying on duplicates (it's just a more compact way to implement multisets aka bags).

Comment: @qollin: I'm not sure you can rely on there always being an id in the relationship table - that may be an implementation detail. And you can build a many-to-many using a "through" table which can have additional columns, such as the count field that Alex suggested.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    ...

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Then:

```
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> c1 = C(a=a1, b=b)
>>> c2 = C(a=a2, b=b)
>>> c3 = C(a=a1, b=b)
```

So, we simply have:

```
>>> assert C.objects.filter(b=b).count == 3
>>> for c in C.objects.filter(b=b):
...     # do something with c.a
```

Comment: I know, not exactly what you are looking for but a way to do something similar :/