# Why does South decide to delete this m2m table?

Tags: django, django-south

I want to add a column to an existing model, and after running "schemamigration --auto" the resulting migration tries to delete another table!  Why would it do that?

my models (simplified) -

```
class A(Model):
    a = CharField()
    b = BooleanField(default=False)   #  <--- this is the new column

class B(Model):                # <---- this is the table South wants to delete
    c = CharField()
    d = ManyToManyField(A, through='C')
```

the result migration-

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Removing M2M table for field d on 'B'
    db.delete_table('B_d')  # <-------  Why is that?
    # Adding field 'b'
    db.add_column('A', 'b', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=False, blank=True), keep_default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also add a through model at the same time/since creating the m2m B_d? It's hard to be sure without seeing more code, but looks like South is ditching the automatic join table because there's now a specified 'through' model that will be used for the join. I'm also assuming that model C does exist :o)

Comment: C does exist :)
I didn't add the the 'through' myself, but looks like one of my coworkers added it and deleted the m2m table himself (without using South), so when (much later) I added a column and created an auto migration south tried to delete the table. And I was wondering how my added column triggered that, Doh!

Comment: Ah. Glad you got to the bottom of it. I'm guessing you know that you can apply that specific migration you made with the --fake option so that you can have a set of migrations that let you replicate the state of the DB for tests/new deployments without having to repeat the manual DB changes your colleague did, too. But just in case you didn't, I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The `through="C"` keyword tells that `C` model will be used as relational table.

Link to documentation: [EXTRA FIELDS ON MANY-TO-MANY RELATIONSHIPS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Other SO question regarding the through keyword: [adding the same object twice to a ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417825/adding-the-same-object-twice-to-a-manytomanyfield)